# Monty Hall Application

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, popular-math

Driver A comes to a 3 way path junction but is not sure which one to take.
Just as he decides to take path 1, a cyclist came by and told driver A all he knows is that he is going on path 3 which would bring him to town. 
Driver A is not heading to town but the seaside. Should he change to path 2?

Driver B encounters the cyclist before he can decide which path to take to the village.
Is his chance less than driver A because he cannot switch?

Answer (score 2):

If we presume that the seaside and town are different directions, each driver has $\frac 12$ chance going on path $1$ or $2$ and $0$ chance going on path $3$.  This is not a Monty Hall situation because the cyclist is not reacting to the driver's choice.

Comment: What if he is? How does it make a difference?

Comment: The point is that Monty knows where the car is and chooses a door to open based on the door originally chosen by the contestant.  In this case the town location is chosen and the information is independent of where the driver planned to go.

Comment: Does intentional vs coincidental revealing of the third door makes a difference? I thought MHP is just a shift of choices of probabilities from (1/3) vs (  2/3   )?

Comment: @shelagh:  I don't understand your question.  Initially the driver thinks the town has $\frac 13$ chance to be in any of the directions.  After the new information, he thinks it is $\frac 12$ for each of two locations, which are completely equivalent in this case.

Comment: The shift occurs because Monty knows about your choice, and he cannot open the door you originally chose. The cyclist has no such restriction.

Comment: Good comments by @Ross & Ben.

Comment: @shelagh:   The details of Monty's strategy matter a lot.  The classic problem is 1) you pick a goat-Monty opens the other goat 2)you pick the car-Monty opens a goat at random.  You need to specify his strategy carefully, then you should be able to calculate the result by following the standard calculation.

Comment: Does it matter whether the host picks the same empty door(town) knowingly or randomly(independent) since the 2nd state of the system ended the same(only seaside and village choices left)?

Comment: @shelagh:  whether the host picks knowingly is essential.  Otherwise he cannot guarantee to show the goat.  In this problem, we are not told what the cyclist would have said if the driver were not going toward town.

Comment: The end result of state 2 is the same whether we 'think' monty actually knows or independently guess the same empty door.

Comment: The guarantee part is to allow the original game to proceed to state 3(to switch or not) ALL the time but if we can proceed to state 3 somehow when monty 'guess' the same door, the decision to shift in probability by switching still depends on the player.